# NoClassDefFoundError when getting BackEnd projet to my FrontEnd

Tags: java, maven

I have a backend project with this in my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>GestionScolaire</groupId>
  <artifactId>GestionScolaire</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
...
```

Then my FrontEnd project get the backend project with this in my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>GestionScolaire</groupId>
<artifactId>GestionScolaireWeb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<description>project_Spring</description>
<name>GestionScolaireWeb</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>  
<dependency>
    <groupId>GestionScolaire</groupId>
    <artifactId>GestionScolaire</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

Matiere

```
package model;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
public class Matiere {

...
```

I have this error when starting my server:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Matiere`

You guys have any idea of why I have this error?

Thanks!

Comment: My colleague had created 2 "web project". So classes were in the WEB-INF folder.... Thank you guys anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least part of the problem lies in this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>GestionScolaire</groupId>
    <artifactId>GestionScolaire</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

If you're including an artifact of type war, you can't use the classes from its `WEB-INF/classes` folder like I think you are trying to do, so the error you are seeing is expected behavior.

A war doesn't behave like a jar.

Regarding possible solutions, I'd like to mention that a WAR project in Maven can also "publish" its `classes` as a jar. 
This [link here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html) describes it better:

> How do I create a JAR containing the classes in my webapp?
>
> ```
> If you would simply like to package the classes and resources as a JAR in WEB-INF/lib rather than as loose files under WEB-INF/classes,
> ```
>
> use the following configuration:
>
> ```
>           <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.1.0</version>
>             <configuration>
>               <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
>             </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>
> If you need to re-use this JAR in another project, the recommended approach is to move the classes to a separate module that builds a
> ```
>
> JAR, and then declare a dependency on that JAR from your webapp as
>   well as from any other projects that need it.
>
> ```
> If you can't move the classes to another project, you can deploy the classes and resources included in your webapp as an "attached"
> ```
>
> artifact, with a classifier, by using the following configuration:
>
> ```
>     <project>
>       ...
>       <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
>       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>       ...
>       <build>
>         <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.1.0</version>
>             <configuration>
>               <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
>             </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>         </plugins>
>       </build>
>       ...
>     </project>
>
> This will result in two artifacts being deployed: mywebapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war and mywebapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar.
> ```